# Java - Implement threading in large input set

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I need to do some computations/processing on a large set of ids (about 100k to 1 Million). Since the number of ids is quite large and each processing does take some time, i was thinking about implementing threads in my Java code.

Assuming we cant have 100K threads running at once, how do i implement threading in this case ?

Note - The only solution i can think of is have about 100 or more threads running where each thread would process about a 1000 or more IDs.

Comment: Take the total number of id's to process. Then divide that by the number of available processors to the system and create that many threads. Then assign each thread a portion of the work = to total/processors ids

Comment: What does processing the IDs require: cpu, memory, disk, network, ...? Do you have just a single machine or is there a possibility of using several?

Comment: processing requires cpu and memory. we just have access to a single machine.

Comment: Use [Thread Pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) to accomplish the work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Java's built in thread pooling and executors.

```
ExecutorService foo =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
foo.submit(new MyRunnable());
```

There are various thread pools you can create to tailor how many you want, if it's dynamic, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using ThreadPool:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class ThreadIDS implements Runnable
{
    public static final int totalIDS = 1000000;
    int start;
    int range;
    public ThreadIDS(int start, int range)
    {
        this.start=start;
        this.range=range;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        int eachThread = totalIDS/availableProcessors + 1;
        ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(availableProcessors);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < availableProcessors ; i++)
        {
            threads.submit(new ThreadIDS(i*eachThread, eachThread));
        }   
        while(!threads.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish");
    }

    public void processID(int id)
    {

    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = start ; i < Math.min(start+range, totalIDS) ; i++)
        {
            processID(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Edited the run method. Since we add 1 when dividing to avoid integer division making us miss ids, we could potentially run over the totalIDS limit. The Math.min avoids that.

If you don't want to use ThreadPools, then change the main to:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    int eachThread = totalIDS/availableProcessors + 1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < availableProcessors ; i++)
    {
        new Thread(new ThreadIDS(i * eachThread, eachThread)).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not recommend managing the threads manually, instead use a thread pool (as noted in my comment on question)

Comment: Thanks, but this assumes that all the processors are solely available for this processing only, which would not be the case obviously.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi basically the fact the native threads will be created on different cores is JVM's and OS' job. You can go further using Java SE 7 [Fork and Join](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/fork-join-422606.html).

Comment: Not sure why somebody downvoted this. Anyway, IMO it would be worth to show both examples

Comment: @AnkitRustagi When creating a thread we don't even decide what processor it will go on. By using an amount of threads = to the number of processors, you allow the OS to use the cores if they're free. If a core elsewhere is being used then the os will end up assigning 2 threads here to the same processor. This simply allows the  OS to utilize the cores if it can.

Answer (score 0):

Run as many threads as you have CPU cores (Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()). Let each thread runs loop like this:

```
public void run() {
   while (!ids.isEmpty()) {
     Id id = ids.poll(); // exact access method depends on how your set of ids is organized
     processId(id);
   }
}
```

Comparing to using thread pool, this is simpler and requires less memory (no need to create Runnable for each id).

Answer (score 0):

Splitting your work into 4 Runnables (1 per core) is probably not the best idea if there is any variation in processing time for a given ID. A better solution would be to split your work up into small chunks so that one core doesn't get stuck with all the "hard" work while the other 3 cores plow through theirs and then do nothing.

You could split your tasks into small chunks in advance and submit them to a ThreadPoolExecutor, but it might be better to use the Fork/Join framework. It's designed to handle this type of thing very efficiently.

Something like this would make sure all 4 cores stayed busy until all the work was done:

```
public class Test
{
    public void workTest()
    {
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();  //Defaults to # of cores

        List<ObjectThatWeProcess> work = getWork(); //Get IDs or whatever
        FJAction action = new FJAction(work);
        pool.invoke(action);        
    }

    public static class FJAction extends RecursiveAction
    {
        private static final workSize = 1000; //Only do work if 1000 objects or less
        List<ObjectThatWeProcess> work;

        FJAction(List<ObjectThatWeProcess> work)
        {
            this.work = work;
        }

        public void compute()
        {
            if(work.size() > workSize)
            {
                invokeAll(new FJAction(work.subList(0,work.size()/2)),
                          new FJAction(work.subList(work.size()/2,work.size())));
            }
            else
                processWork();
        }

        private void processWork()
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

You could also extend RecursiveTask<T> if the "work" returned a value that was relevant to you.